# Would it be valid to change the いい in (verb)ても良い into a negative?

Tags: grammar

E.G. 言わなくても良くない

I've always been curious about this, but none of the books or classes I've had ever approached it

Comment: So what exactly do you wanna mean with that? A double negative that becomes a positive?

Comment: I'm just curious if it means anything of significance. Only ever heard used as (verb)てもいい

Answer (score 5, accepted):

～てもいい basically means "It's okay even if you do...", eg:

> 「言っ**てもいい**」 -- "It's okay even if you say" → "It's okay to say / You *may* say"
>   「言わ**なくてもいい**」 -- "It's okay even if you don't say" → "You *don't have to* say"

To say "You may not do..." or "You have to do...", you'd use ～（なく）て**は**いけない, rather than ～（なく）て**も**良くない (×も→◎は):

> 「言っ**てはいけない**」 -- "It won't do if you say" → "You *may not* say"
>   「言わ**なくてはいけない**」 -- "It won't do if you don't say" → "You *have to* say"

～て**も**良くない, ～て**も**いけない would usually mean "Doing ... is not good (either)":

> 「食べすぎても良くない/いけないが、全く食べなくても良くない/いけない。」
>   or 「食べすぎるのも良くない/いけないが、全く食べないのも良くない/いけない。」
>   "Eating too much is not good, but not eating at all is not good, either."

You'd also use ～なくても良くない？ at the end of a sentence in casual conversation, like this:

> 「学校なんて行かなくてもよくない？」 -- "You don't need to go to school, right?"
>   「そんなこと言わなくてもよくない？」 -- "You don't need to say that, do you?" "Do you really need to say that?"

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no grammatical sense.  The ～てもいい form means, literally speaking "Even if you do ~, it's OK" (or, in the negative, "Even if you don't do ~, it's ok").  If you want to use ～てもよくない, what you are trying to say is, "Even if you don't do ~, it's not OK".  What would such a phrase mean, or how would it be used?  I don't think such a phrase would make sense, so I'm going to go with a "don't do this".

Comment: I'm not sure about this specific case (that's why I didn't answer the question myself), but I believe double negatives are def a thing in japanese. Your answer makes it seem like it is not. For instance the pattern ない＋と＋いけない。Is a double negative that ends up with a positive meaning. I guess op wants to know whether this is possible or not here.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Double negatives are absolutely a thing in Japanese, that is true.  However, I'm not sure what the OP is trying to say with this double-negative, and so whatever it is, is probably wrong.